# Proving $\lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{e^h - 1}{h} = 1$ when differentiating $e^x$ by first principles

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, exponential-function

The definition of $e$ as continual compounding is found computationally as:
$\lim_{n\to \infty} \Big(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\Big)^n = e$

If we let $h=\dfrac{1}{n}$, then $e = \lim_{h\to 0} (1+h)^{\frac{1}{h}}$

Differentiating $e^x$ by first principles we get:

$f(x)=e^x$

$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{e^{x+h}-e^x}{h}$

$=\lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{e^x\times e^h-e^x}{h}$

$=\lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{e^x(e^h - 1)}{h}$

$=e^x \times \lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{e^h - 1}{h}$

Now, I know the result of the limit is going to be $1$. So my intuition is that I should be able to substitute in the compounding expression for $e$ and then manipulate the limit in the derivative to yield $1$. So by reverse engineering the expected solution I have the following:

$\lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{e^h - 1}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{[\lim_{h\to 0} (1+h)^{\frac{1}{h}}]^h - 1}{h}$

$= \lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{[(1+h)^\frac{1}{h}]^h -1}{h}$

$= \lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{(1+h)-1}{h}$

$= \lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{h}{h}$

$= \lim_{h\to 0} 1$

$= 1$

My question is regarding this step:

$\lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{[\lim_{h\to 0} (1+h)^{\frac{1}{h}}]^h - 1}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{[(1+h)^\frac{1}{h}]^h -1}{h}$

I believe it must be true since it produces the expected result, but I'm unsure how to justify removing the nested limit.

Comment: $\textbf{Hint:}$ you have $0/0$ this L’Hospitals rule can be applied.

Comment: Applying the limit nesting as you have conflates the outer $h$ with the inner and produces the correct result but on a poor foundation.

Comment: $lim_{h→0}\frac{[(1+h)^{1/h}]}^h}{h}$

Comment: @coffeemath precisely.

Comment: @HossienS'MyMathYourMath' I can't get the mathjax to work. I was trying to say that step doesn't give the same thing.

Comment: @coffeemath I get what you meant lol

Comment: What I meant was this: The second displayed line simplifies to limit of $(1+h)/h$ as $h \to 0.$ But that limit is undefined. so cannot say last thing on first line is equal to second line.

Comment: In the question, the last expression is missing a $-1$ in the numerator.

Comment: The way forward here is to go back to the definition of limit and define what you mean by the limits, then show that your workings apply. Otherwise there is nothing you can do, you are just playing around with limit symbols like a physicist or something.

Comment: If $e:=\lim_{n\to \infty} (1+\frac 1n)^n$ by definiton, how is $b^x; b> 0; x\in \mathbb R$ defined? I think that is actually key.  I *think* (it's late and I'm tired) that we usually define $\ln x=\int_1^x \frac 1t dt$ and then prove that if $\ln e = \int_1^e \frac 1t dt$ then $e = \lim_{n\to \infty}(1 + \frac 1n)^n$.  You might what to do the opposite and ife we define $e:=\lim (1+\frac 1n)^n$ then prove $\int_1^e \frac 1t dt = 1$.  From there maybe your result would follow.

Answer (score 2):

If you know $(e^x)'=e^x$, then by the definition of the derivative,  $$1=e^0=(e^x)'(0)=\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac {e^h-e^0}h=\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac {e^h-1}h$$.

But I guess that begs the question.

---

There's L'hopital.  But it also requires knowing that derivative:

$$\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac {e^h-1}h=\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac {e^h}1=e^0=1$$

---

If you know the power series $$e^x=\sum_n\dfrac {x^n}{n!}$$.  Then it's pretty easy to see that $(e^x)'=e^x$.

---

Or, you could use the fact that $e^x$ and $\ln x$ are inverses.   If you know $(\ln x)'=1/x$, then since $e^{\ln x}=x$, you get by the chain rule that $(e^x)'(\ln x)\cdot 1/x=1$.  So $(e^x)'(\ln x)=x$.  And $(e^x)'$ is $\ln^{-1} x=e^x$.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I think not just your first point but all of them are question begging.

L'hopital's assumes you can differentiate the numerator already.

Power series are constructed using derivatives.

The derivative of $y=\ln{x}$ is found by implicitly differentiating $e^y=x$

Comment: You've gotta start somewhere.  Plus that's not the only way to get $\ln$'s derivative.

Comment: Sorry, yes you're correct there's other ways - it's just the way I normally teach it since it's the most immediate if you already know derivative of e^x. Just to give more context, I'm a high school teacher in NSW, Australia and was looking for a more 'satisfying' way to refine how I teach the derivative of e^x based on knowing just the definition of e and differentiation by first principles.

Comment: Normally I'd do 2^x and 3^x by first principles with the class, noticing that the limit evaluates to a number either side of 1, then put (a^x-1)/x into Geogebra and see that a=e is the special number that makes the limit 1. In our syllabus we don't do derivatives of logs until later, otherwise ideally I'd do derivative of lnx by first principles first and then could use that to do e^x without any question begging or an extra computation.

Comment: Ok.  For instance I like to define $\ln x=\int_1^x1/t\rm dt$.  Then it's derivative is immediate by the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Answer (score 0):

You may also be interested in the following (equivalent) definition of the exponential function:
\begin{align*}
\exp(x) = 1 + x + \frac{x^{2}}{2!} + \frac{x^{3}}{3!} + \ldots = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{n!}
\end{align*}

Such power series converges for every possible value of $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Hence we conclude that $e^{h} - 1 = h + o(h)$.

Having said that, the proposed limit can be computed in the following manner:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{h} - 1}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h + o(h)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0}\left(1 + \frac{o(h)}{h}\right) = 1
\end{align*}

**EDIT**

This is particularly useful to obtain the derivative of $e^{x}$ by the limit definition:
\begin{align*}
(e^{x})' = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{x + h} - e^{x}}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{x}(e^{h} - 1)}{h} = e^{x}
\end{align*}

and we are done.

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

How is $b^x; b > 0; x\in \mathbb R$ defined?

If we define $b^x = \lim_{q_i\to x;q_i\in \mathbb Q} b^q$ where $\{q_i\}$ is *any* sequence of rationals so that $q_i \to x$,  then we have the rather ... surreal:

$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac {e^h -1}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0}\lim_{q_i\to h}\frac {\lim_{n\to\infty} (1+\frac 1n)^n)^h-1}{q_{h,i}}$

where for each $h$ we have $q_{h,i}$ be a sequence of rational that converge to that $h$.

Now we can, as we are taking limits, take any sub limits we like if that will make things simpler.  So.... bear with me....   As you know, we can always replace a limit of $\lim_{h\to 0}f(h)$ with $\lim_{n\to \infty} f(\frac 1n)$.  And if we restrict $n\in \mathbb Z$ we have $\frac 1n \in \mathbb Q$ so we can let the nescessary $q_{h,i}\to h$ all be equal to $\frac 1n$ as the *constant* sequence $\frac 1n,\frac 1n, \frac 1n....$ certainly *does* converge to $\frac 1n$.

So more surreal but ultimately... hey, that's legit! we have

$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac {e^h - 1}h =$
$\lim_{h=\frac 1n; q_i=h=\frac 1n;i\to \infty; n\to\infty}\frac {((1+\frac 1n)^n)^{q_i}-1}h=$
$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac {((1+\frac 1n)^n)^{\frac 1n} - 1}{\frac 1n}=$
$\lim_{n\to \infty}n\cdot ((1+\frac 1n)-1)=\lim_{n\to \infty}n\cdot \frac 1n = \lim_{n\to\infty}1=1$

Now... that assumes we have defined $b^x;b> 0; x\in \mathbb R$ as $\lim_{q_i\to x}b^{q_i}$

Most calculus books don't.

More standard is to define $\ln x = \int_0^x \frac 1t dt$ and to define $exp(x)$ to be the inverse of this.  That is $exp(x)=y \iff \int_1^y\frac 1t dt = x$.  And define $b^x = exp(x\cdot \ln b)$ and $e=exp(1)$ or in other words $e$ is the positive real value where $\int_1^e\frac 1t dt = 1$.

In that case $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac {b^h -1}h=\ln b$ sort of falls into place by definition.

As does proving that  $\lim_{n\to \infty}(1+\frac 1n)^n=e$.

(See https://www2.clarku.edu/faculty/djoyce/ma121/elimit.pdf)